# Flash Degredation Alternative Text In IE When File Not Found

Tags: flash

Searching in Google for ways to gracefully degrade Flash naturally yields many results relating to the lack / disabling of browser support for Flash.

However, my question relates to what happens when the actual file (e.g. my-videeo-typo.swf) cannot be found - i.e. the path is broken. In Firefox it seems to work as expected whereby the alternative text kicks in - e.g. "We could not load this content (the file may not exist, or you may need to install Flash)". In Internet Explorer the  element (e.g. 500x500px) loads but it is empty/blank instead of displaying alternative text.

My code is thus:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="my-videeo-typo.swf" width="500" height="500">
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
    width="500" height="500">
  <param name="movie" value="my-videeo-typo.swf" />
<!-->
  <param name="loop" value="false">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <p>We could not load this content (the file may not exist, or you may need to install Flash)</p>
</object>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitively be using [SWFobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to insert a flash in an HTML page. You will then forget any of these issues.